# Learning CSS, how to use stylesheet with master page

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm trying to learn to use stylesheets. I have build several websites, but never used stylesheets.

My first try is to repeat an image at the top of the page to create some kind of header.
So I have created a stylesheet that looks like:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('../images/MasterPageHead.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Now on my master page, I have added the line:

```
<link href="CSS/MasterPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The body of my master page looks like this:

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server" >
    <div>
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

      </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Now how can I show this image at the top of the page?

rg,
Eric

Comment: What you have should work as intended: http://jsfiddle.net/zjNtW/

Comment: add *{margin:0px;padding:0px;} to your stylesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there is something inside the page to give it a `height`, or specify a `min-height` inside your current `body` CSS rule.